# References to Streaming Delta Live Tables

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql, delta-live-tables

It was my understanding that references to streaming delta live tables require the use of the function `STREAM()`, supplying the table name as an argument.

Given below is a code snippet that I found in one of the demo notebooks that Databricks provide. Here, I see the use of `STREAM()` in the `FROM` clause, but it has not been used in the `LEFT JOIN`, even though that table is also a streaming table. This query still works.

What exactly is the correct syntax here?

```
CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING LIVE TABLE sales_orders_cleaned(
  CONSTRAINT valid_order_number EXPECT (order_number IS NOT NULL) ON VIOLATION DROP ROW
)
COMMENT "The cleaned sales orders with valid order_number(s) and partitioned by order_datetime."
AS
  SELECT f.customer_id, f.customer_name, f.number_of_line_items, 
         timestamp(from_unixtime((cast(f.order_datetime as long)))) as order_datetime, 
         date(from_unixtime((cast(f.order_datetime as long)))) as order_date, 
         f.order_number, f.ordered_products, c.state, c.city, c.lon, c.lat, c.units_purchased, c.loyalty_segment
  FROM STREAM(LIVE.sales_orders_raw) f
  LEFT JOIN LIVE.customers c
    ON c.customer_id = f.customer_id
    AND c.customer_name = f.customer_name
```

Just for reference, given below are the other two tables that act as inputs to the above query,

```
CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING LIVE TABLE sales_orders_raw
COMMENT "The raw sales orders, ingested from /databricks-datasets."
AS SELECT * FROM cloud_files("/databricks-datasets/retail-org/sales_orders/", "json", map("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes", "true"))

CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING LIVE TABLE customers
COMMENT "The customers buying finished products, ingested from /databricks-datasets."
AS SELECT * FROM cloud_files("/databricks-datasets/retail-org/customers/", "csv");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [different types of joins on the Spark streams](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#join-operations):

- stream-static join. ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/workflows/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-incremental-data#--stream-batch-joins))  This is exactly your case, when you have `STREAM(LIVE.sales_orders_raw)` for orders, but the customers stream is considered static (it's read on each microbatch, and represents the state at moment of invocation).  This is usually a case for your kind of functionality.
- stream-stream join.  In this case, both streams may need to align against each other, because data may come later, etc.   In this case both streams will use `STREAM(LIVE....)` syntax.  But it may not be the best case for you, because both streams need to wait until late data come, etc. - You will need to define a watermark for both streams, etc. Look for Spark documentation regarding that.